# Print a boxplot for every column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
for column in data:
    plt.figure()
    data.boxplot([column])
```

**Error:**

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Some of the columns are object type some are float, int. I want to plot the `object` type also

Comment: `data[column].plot.box()`?

Comment: Can you give us a piece of your data please, to see and test the problem please